# Jquery UI Datepicker above / below classes

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

If a text input which has a datepicker is close to the bottom of the window, the datepicker div will appear above the input. If the input is close to the top of the window, the datepicker div will appear below the input. If possible, I want the datepicker div to have different class names on these situations.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but the API has an option:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOptions
(doesn't work, only aplies to animation direction

I would search for a event that triggers right before or just after the displaying and then get value from this direction value and change the classes accordingly.

You could use a beforeShow, maybe you can find some info there...

Here's a jsFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/Bd6sU/1/

```
 $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
     beforeShow: function (i, o){
     }
 });
```

I noticed jQuery positions the ui-datepicker-div absolutely, and not relative to the input field. So that doesn't help either....

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but **showOptions** option is for setting the direction of the appearing animation (if **showAnim** option is set). I could not understand how to use the **onSelect** option.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that... I'll update the answer. I also noticed that onSelect fires when you select a new date, not when the thing opens....